No static files over Nginx + Django
I know there are many such questions. But I've tried a lot of what I've found and nothing helps.
I have a combination of Django + uWSGI + Nginx + PostgreSQL.
Static file was collected by python manage.py collectstatic in movies_admin/static directory.
I'm logging into Django admin at a local address via nginx 127.0.0.1/admin. The page itself is loaded, but only the text, fields and the like. No graphics - that my problem.
My docker-compose file:
version: '3'

services:
  django:
    restart: always
    build: movies_admin/.
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    container_name: work_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: 'postgres:${PG_VER}'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    container_name: work_database
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ${DB_VOLUME_CATALOG_PATH}:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  nginx:
    image: 'nginx:${NGINX_VER}'
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_CONF_FILE}:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ${NGINX_CONFD_CATALOG}:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - ${STATIC_PATH}:/var/www/static/:ro
    container_name: work_nginx
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - "80:80"

I checked. The static directory is mounted in the '/var/www/static/' directory of the nginx container.
My site.conf:
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/static/;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://django:8000;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ {
        log_not_found off;
        expires 90d;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}

Part of my settings.py:
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
    '/opt/app/static/',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


WhiteNoise was not needed. The problem turned out to be in the site.conf file. The file itself is in order.
In this state everything worked.
Removed css and js from:
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|js)$ {
        log_not_found off;
        expires 90d;
    }

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://django:8000;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/static/;
    }
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$ {
        log_not_found off;
        expires 90d;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}

